# Ensure that image was captured from the Camera in React

Tags: reactjs, face-recognition, biometrics

So I am building a face recognition based login system. I am using React on the Frontend and a Python based API for the backend.

I am using the "react-webcam" package to click a photo of the user and sending it to the backend endpoint to login. The code for this is

```
const face_uri = face.canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg")

const request = new Request('/api/login',{
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({
    face:face_uri
  }),
  headers: {
    accept: 'application/json',
  },
})

const response = await fetch(request);
```

I do face detecting and matching on the server side and return a JWT if a face is found and matched.

My problem is anyone could get a base64 encoded image of another person and post that to my endpoint '/api/login' and gain access to someone else's account.

How do I ensure that the image being sent to the backend was clicked right now from the camera?
Please let me know of any suggestions you have, even if it involves using a completely different approach, language, framework etc.

Comment: image metadata and compare time?

Comment: @RohitKashyap I was thinking of it but its really easy to image metadata, look at this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101688/how-to-get-edit-exif-meta-data-of-multiple-images). So anyone could take a jpeg photo of someone else's face, change the metadata, base64 encode it and post it to gain access. Edit